# PyParse - if no match return spcific statement

Tags: python, pyparsing

How do I return specific statement ( e.g - domain: [DISABLED]) if no match is found( no VTP domain, or no VTP mode ) in the following code :

```
testData = """

vtp domain XXxxXX
vtp mode transparent
udld enable
snmp-server enable traps vtp
"""
print("----------------------")
# simple grammar to match #vtp
ident = Word(alphas, alphanums+"_")
macroDef = Literal("vtp") + ident.setResultsName("name") + restOfLine.setResultsName("value")
for lit,ResN,RoLResN in macroDef.scanString( testData ):
    print('{0:5}{1:7}{2:1}{3:15}{4:}'.format("-",lit.name,":", lit.value,"[ENABLED]")) 
print("******************************************************************************")
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `scanString`, you are more in control than pyparsing about what values are detected as missing. Since your pyparsing expression only looks for one setting at a time, it really only knows about the current line being parsed. To detect a missing value using this method, you'll need to keep your own list of what elements have been found, and then at the end, act on those that were expected but not found (fill in a default, or prompt the user for a value, or raise an exception, or ...).

For pyparsing to detect the presence or absence of a parameter, you would need to define a parser that reads all of the parameters at once, and then add a parse action to do the validation. Then you would use likely use `parseString` instead of `scanString`.